# Is it they who has or have?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Source:  http://www.thecricketmonthly.com/story/998521/the-kotla-shambles

Please look at the following

> Undoubtedly these are shocking details. But legal cases, allegations and political slugfests are unable to capture the experience of the spectator. ***It is he who has to*** endure the consequences of the mess that has erupted inside the association.

Here in the above highlighted part, the spectator in question is singular, which of the following two would be correct to use

a) It is they ***who has to*** endure the consequences.

b) It is they ***who have to*** endure the consequences.

Which one is correct of the two?

Answer (score 4):

The subject is "they", so you'd use the plural.  "they ... have to" rather than "they ... has to".

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of phrase, use the structure "*present tense of to have* + infinitive".

For example:

- *I have* to go
- *He has* to eat
- *They have* to do their homework

So in this case,

It is **they** who **have** *to endure* the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

B would be the correct one to use.

While there is the [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) when it comes to colloquial English, this form always, *always*, follows the same form of a pluralized form of "they". To say that someone eats a sandwich, you could say these things to refer to the same person:

> He **eats** a sandwich.

or

> They (singular) **eat** a sandwich.